# How to add an element in an instanced class arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this code to create a class User

```
public class User {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<User> owners = new ArrayList<>();


    public User(String name, ArrayList<User> owners) {
        this.name = name;
        this.owners = owners;

    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void addOwner(User owner) {
        owners.add(owner);

    }
```

If i create an instance of this class with

```
User jhil = new User(name, new ArrayList<>());
```

What do i do to add a string element to the arraylist

I've tried with the addOwner method with

```
jhil.addOwner(jhilsara);
```

but i get a the method addOwner(String) is undefined for the type User error

I've also tried with the ArrayList add method

```
jhil.add(jhilsara);
```

But that doesn't work either.

So my question is what do i need to do in order to add something to the arraylist of an instanced of my class User

Comment: Apparently `jhilsara` is a String. You need a User.

Comment: Then how do i change my method so that it accepts a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your ArrayList set to contain objects of the User class, not Strings. Change the declaration of it to:

```
private ArrayList<String> owners = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then, you also have to change addOwner to:

```
public void addOwner(String owner) {
    owners.add(owner);
}
```